Edit Hex values in JSON file in Visual Studio
I'm using a JSON file to configure settings in my app.
Some of the settings I would like to enter as hex values.
I using Visual Studio to edit the JSON file. But when I enter a hex values it assumes that it's a string rather than a hex values and therefore it puts the value in quotation marks.
This also happens when I copy and paste JSON values that contains hex values.
Is there a way to avoid this?

What do you mean "hex values"? In JSON, "A number is represented in base 10 using decimal digits."

By hex value I mean - 0X0F will represent the value 15.

VS is right, that either needs to be a string or converted to decimal notation. Otherwise it's not valid JSON (might be valid in e.g. JSON5).

True - VS is doing the right thing according to standard JSON formatting. You might even argue that I'm not using pure JSON formatting because i put in values like 0x0F.
However - I can type 0x0F and also have it read and understood by using e.g. Newtonsoft JSON. So it would be great if there was a way to diasable the "auto-correction" in VS where it changes 0x0F to "0x0F". I just don't know if it's possible and how.

If you want to disable the "auto-correction" in VS from changing 0x0F to "0x0F", including when copying and pasting JSON values ​​that contain hex values, you need to complete the following:
Open your VS, Tools > Options > Text Editor > JSON > Advanced > Formatting, then change both Automatic formatting and Format on paste to Off.

Thanks @cody Liang - that was what I was looking for. I was trying to solve this by looking at Schemas, but this is a much better approach
